# Pressing the button from js without jquery and getelementby

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm fighting with an auto logging script with js. Currently, I'm pasting my username and password to the input fields. It seems like the site is blocking the possibility to click `LogIn` button after I call `document.getElementBy` and set the value of the input file. If I don't execute the script which fills login and password fields then I can call press the button LogIn from js. The document.getelementbyid see LoginButton but can't press him when data to inputs was copied. Is there any possibility to fill username and password inputs without using `GetElementById.value='smth'`? I also tried jquery but the site blocks button LogIn but if I write text to both fields from my keyboard, then button is not blocking. Help me, please.
Thank you in advice.

Comment: Can you put a snippet of the code? Try using **submit** method.

Comment: You could try `document.querySelector("[name=username]")` or whatever the name is for the input box. If it's in a `<form>` you can just fill in the user / pass however and if the button is disabled just select the form and `.submit()` it

Comment: The website is probably updating its internal "form is valid" status (and therefore whether clicking the LogIn button will work) based on an event like `input` or `change`; you need to also simulate one of these.

Comment: This is not a form and submit doesnt work : /

Comment: @thinktwice I cant submit, because this is not inside a form : /

Comment: @ChrisG could You tell me more about this and give some example ?

Comment: I've messed around with this, couldn't get it to work though: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-rgb-kulh3?file=/public/autolog.js

Comment: Unfortunately I cant simulate this. I tried clicking on each field in js after inserting data to inputs but it doesnt work. If i try to click with my mouse on each input field and press simple space after filling data from my js then te button is unlocked and may be pressed with mouse. I dont know what im doing wrong but it's weird.

Answer (score 0):

explicitly set the disabled property to false so it becomes active

```
document.getElementById("submit").disabled = false;
```

Comment: I tried this and button is not disabled. It doesn't work

Comment: you want to disable or enable?? i tried on the same thing you provided,it works

Comment: tried both. The button is always enabled. If i click by mouse on inputs (username, password) and press just space for example after I fill them with my js code then login button becomes avaiable to click. I also tried to do some click and space events, dispatched them on input fields but it works only if I do it by mouse myself.. I have no idea

Comment: hey hey calm down, above code activates even if the fields are empty, or entered, with space or not , with or without mouse, if you change it true, it'll disable whatever the condition is!!!

Comment: so I made button.disable = false; but it still doesn't work

Comment: i tested your page, don't know why, your page executes every function! function shouldn't execute unless executed, but wait for 5 seconds and fire your code it works perfectly, debug why your page is executing the every function it encounters

Comment: i'm working on different project which is not linked to my account